# What is the path of the loaded dll?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, dllimport

I am loading a `dll` with `ctypes` under Cygwin with the following:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('foo.dll')
```

How can I get the absolute path of my dll?

The problem is that I have absolutely no clues where the dll is located. Can I relate on the following to get this information?

```
subprocess.Popen(["which", lib], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().strip()
```

Comment: Do you want to get the absolute path after loading the DLL or before loading it?

Comment: Of course after loading it

Comment: That should be easy, assuming Cygwin supports `dladdr` and you have a function name in the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unix, the path of a loaded shared library can be determined by calling `dladdr` with the address of a symbol in the library, such as a function.

**Example:**

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

libdl = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library('dl'))

class Dl_info(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('dli_fname', ctypes.c_char_p),
                ('dli_fbase', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('dli_sname', ctypes.c_char_p),
                ('dli_saddr', ctypes.c_void_p))

libdl.dladdr.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(Dl_info))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    info = Dl_info()
    result = libdl.dladdr(libdl.dladdr, ctypes.byref(info))

    if result and info.dli_fname:
        libdl_path = info.dli_fname.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    else:
        libdl_path = u'Not Found'

    print(u'libdl path: %s' % libdl_path)
```

**Output:**

```
libdl path: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
```

Comment: I don't have `dladdr` available in my `ctypes.CDLL` instance

Comment: So Cygwin doesn't support `dladdr` (yet). And ctypes doesn't support `stdcall` in Cygwin, right? Thus we can't load kernel32.dll and call `GetModuleFileNameW`. If you're in a 64-bit process, you can try it with `CDLL` anyway, since 64-bit Windows has a single ABI. But I don't have Cygwin installed to test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and do not need a programmatical solution for instance if you are debugging something, you can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to look which DLLs python.exe has loaded.